# Django -> post and get work, but loading a fixture gets a "no such column error'

Tags: python, django, orm

I've created a new model, and can post and get, and I receive all the fields. This indicates the underlying table is correct. I also manually checked my migrations and all the fields are there. And manually check the serializer (which is observably working via post/get).

However, when I try the `dumpdata` or `loaddata` command, I get the error: "no such column: creator". Why would these two command think the field doesn't exist when the other aspects of the app can use it?

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing the model definition, or the command you're running, or the error output, or _anything_?

Comment: At your earliest convenience, you may consider [attaching](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74787965/edit) code examples (models.py, fixtures.json) to this post to help answer it. ([Courtesy Tomas Varžgalys](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74788247/2).)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your model doesn't have a `creator` field or you just haven't migrated it yet (`python manage.py migrate`).

Comment: The executable `python` does not exist on some systems (e.g., some versions of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)). The name of the executable may be `python3`.

Comment: This belongs as a comment, not an answer.